# systemctl is-active output wrong state

Tags: systemd

### Have problem

At the same host , Why when I use kill to kill a program ilogtaild, This ilogtaild unit is still active?

```
#systemctl status ilogtaild
● ilogtaild.service - SYSV: ilogtail is log collect agent of Simple Log Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/ilogtaild; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-08-18 12:38:07 CST; 1min 59s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 33718 ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/ilogtaild stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 33745 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/ilogtaild start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ilogtaild.service
           ├─33747 /usr/local/ilogtail/ilogtail
           └─33749 /usr/local/ilogtail/ilogtail


#kill -9 33747 33749


#systemctl status ilogtaild
● ilogtaild.service - SYSV: ilogtail is log collect agent of Simple Log Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/ilogtaild; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2017-08-18 12:38:07 CST; 2min 9s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 33718 ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/ilogtaild stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 33745 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/ilogtaild start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

Look here

```
#systemctl is-active ilogtaild
active
```

ilogtaild configure

```
#systemctl cat ilogtaild
# /etc/systemd/system/ilogtaild.service
[Unit]
Documentation=man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
SourcePath=/etc/rc.d/init.d/ilogtaild
Description=SYSV: ilogtail is log collect agent of Simple Log Service
Before=runlevel2.target runlevel3.target runlevel4.target runlevel5.target shutdown.target z_nic_irq_set.service muahao.service e2e-qos.service
After=network-online.target network.service khotfix.service
Conflicts=shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=forking
Restart=no
TimeoutSec=5min
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
KillMode=process
GuessMainPID=no
RemainAfterExit=yes
ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/ilogtaild start
ExecStop=/etc/rc.d/init.d/ilogtaild stop
```

### No problem

```
#systemctl status crond
● crond.service - Command Scheduler
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/crond.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2017-08-18 12:43:25 CST; 920ms ago
 Main PID: 36532 (crond)
   CGroup: /system.slice/crond.service
           └─36532 /usr/sbin/crond -n -m/dev/null


#kill -9 36532

#systemctl status crond
● crond.service - Command Scheduler
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/crond.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: signal) since Fri 2017-08-18 12:43:36 CST; 2s ago
  Process: 36532 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/crond -n $CRONDARGS (code=killed, signal=KILL)
 Main PID: 36532 (code=killed, signal=KILL)
```

Look here

```
#systemctl is-active crond
failed
```

configure

```
#systemctl cat crond
# /usr/lib/systemd/system/crond.service
[Unit]
Description=Command Scheduler
After=auditd.service systemd-user-sessions.service time-sync.target

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/etc/sysconfig/crond
ExecStart=/usr/sbin/crond -n $CRONDARGS
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 ● ilogtaild.service - SYSV: ilogtail is log collect agent of Simple Log Service
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/ilogtaild; static; vendor preset: disabled)
…
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
```

You aren't using an explicitly written systemd service unit.  You are using a unit generated by `systemd-sysv-generator`, from a van Smoorenburg `rc` script that lacks LSB header information.  `systemd-sysv-generator` takes a one-size-fits-all approach, modified with some guesswork.  van Smoorenburg `rc` scripts may or may not start long-running dæmon processes, may or may not employ PID files, and so forth.  `systemd-sysv-generator` tries to generate service units that accommodate these possibilities.

The auto-generated service units have either `RemainAfterExit=false` or `RemainAfterExit=true` according to whether the header information in the van Smoorenburg `rc` script names a PID file.  (If it names a PID file, `RemainAfterExit` is `false`.)

So:

- In the short term, your `/etc/rc.d/init.d/ilogtaild` should name a PID file with a RedHat `pidfile:` header.  Otherwise systemd will continue to assume that it is a van Smoorenburg `rc` script that does not necessarily leave around a long-running dæmon process.
- In the long term, you should stop using `/etc/rc.d/init.d/ilogtaild` and stop relying upon `systemd-sysv-generator` to wrap it in nonce service units.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233581/5132
- Red Hat (1998). *[Writing System V init scripts for Red Hat Linux](http://sensi.org/~alec/unix/redhat/sysvinit.html)*.

Answer (score 1):

Should use RemainAfterExit=no

```
   RemainAfterExit=
       Takes a boolean value that specifies whether the service shall be considered active even when all its processes exited. Defaults to no.
```