# Where is the process running the service?

Tags: ubuntu, process, services, daemon, cntlm

The service is running:

```
» sudo service cntlm status

● cntlm.service - LSB: Authenticating HTTP accelerator for NTLM secured proxies
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/cntlm; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Tue 2018-02-20 12:01:02 CET; 3min 33s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 9215 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/cntlm stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 9298 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/cntlm start (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0
   Memory: 0B
      CPU: 0

Feb 20 12:01:02 host1 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Authenticating HTTP accelerator for NTLM secured proxies...
Feb 20 12:01:02 host1 cntlm[9298]: Starting CNTLM Authentication Proxy: failed!
Feb 20 12:01:02 host1 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Authenticating HTTP accelerator for NTLM secured proxies.
```

But there is no process:

```
» ps -ef | grep cntlm
dangonfast 12466 13067  0 12:05 pts/19   00:00:00 grep --color=auto cntlm
```

Why is that?

Comment: It seems `active (exited)` means "not running" (!?). The daemon was badly configured. I was confused by the `active` flag.

Comment: This is the same as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/387310/ pretty much; and slightly different to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386846/ .  They both have much the same answer as here, though.  It's largely the same thing every time.

Answer (score 0):

The .services generated by `systemd-sysv-generator` have the directive `RemainAfterExit=yes` set. According to the `systemd.service` manpage, RemainAfterExit:

> Takes a boolean value that specifies whether the service shall be considered active even when all its processes exited. Defaults to no.

Comment: For more on which, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233468/ and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/386876/5132.

Answer (score -1):

This service was executed and exited. This is a normal situation for services running in "one-shot" mode. Their definition in /etc/systemd/system/*.service or /usr/lib/systemd/system/*.service may for example include:

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
```

Comment: You probably don't want `Type=oneshot` when running a daemon. Also, `RemainAfterExit=yes` is already set by `systemd-sysv-generator` generated services