# Service Active but (exited)

Tags: debian, iptables, firewall

I have already install firewall (iptables) on a server Debian 8.
The service is active but in (exited) state.

What does "Active: active (exited)" mean ? And how can i fix or change it into (running) ?

```
[root@fw-liv-1-new:~]# systemctl status firewall.service
● firewall.service - LSB: Start daemon at boot time
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/firewall)
   Active: active (exited) since dim. 2017-08-20 18:32:48 CEST; 11min ago

août 20 18:32:46 fw-liv-1-new firewall[623]: ---->Politiques par defaut DROP
août 20 18:32:47 fw-liv-1-new firewall[623]: ---->Chargement des regles LBN input
août 20 18:32:47 fw-liv-1-new firewall[623]: ---->Connexions locales
août 20 18:32:47 fw-liv-1-new firewall[623]: ---->Chargement des regles LBN input
août 20 18:32:47 fw-liv-1-new firewall[623]: ---->Chargement des regles LBN forward
août 20 18:32:48 fw-liv-1-new firewall[623]: ---->Execution de /etc/firewall/firewall_LBN.sh
août 20 18:32:48 fw-liv-1-new firewall[623]: ---->Regles filter INPUT
août 20 18:32:48 fw-liv-1-new firewall[623]: ---->Regles filter FORWARD
août 20 18:32:48 fw-liv-1-new firewall[623]: ---->Regles filter OUTPUT
août 20 18:32:48 fw-liv-1-new systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start daemon at boot time.
```

I also tried to stop/start firewall but status has not been changed.
Could someone help me on this, please ?

Comment: Systemd.........

Comment: _Slightly_ different question to https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386846/ . Slightly different, but largely the same answer.

Answer (score 3):

```
● firewall.service - LSB: Start daemon at boot time
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/firewall)
   Active: active (exited) since dim. 2017-08-20 18:32:48 CEST; 11min ago
```

You aren't using an explicitly written systemd service unit.  You are using a unit generated by `systemd-sysv-generator`, from a van Smoorenburg `rc` script that has LSB header information.  `systemd-sysv-generator` takes a one-size-fits-all approach, modified with some guesswork.  van Smoorenburg `rc` scripts may or may not start long-running dæmon processes, may or may not employ PID files, and so forth.  `systemd-sysv-generator` tries to generate service units that accommodate these possibilities.

The auto-generated service units have `RemainAfterExit=true` when generated from van Smoorenburg `rc` scripts with LSB information.  So when the process executing the script exits, and does not leave any running processes behind the service is still considered "active", with the service process having exited.

This is of course the case for a service that just adjusts a few rules at startup and *does not actually create a dæmon process*, as is the case for your `/etc/init.d/firewall` script.  Ironically, but sadly not unusually, the description on the LSB header in your van Smoorenburg `rc` script — "Start daemon at boot time" — is completely wrong for the `firewall` service.  It does not do that at all.

## Further reading

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/233581/5132