# Is my firewall configured OK?

Tags: systemd, firewall, systemctl, ufw

[image]

```
$ systemctl status ufw
● ufw.service - Uncomplicated firewall
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/ufw.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sun 2021-10-03 15:43:42 +03; 1h 30min ago
     Docs: man:ufw(8)
 Main PID: 28326 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4467)
   CGroup: /system.slice/ufw.service

Oct 03 15:43:39 Cheetah systemd[1]: Starting Uncomplicated firewall...
Oct 03 15:43:42 Cheetah systemd[1]: Started Uncomplicated firewall.
```

Why is `systemctl status ufw` outputting `"active (exited)"` instead of `"active (running)"?` Should I be worried?

```
$ sudo ufw status
Status: active
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From original post: [What does status "active (exited)" mean for a systemd service?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/241970)

> State active (exited) means that systemd has successfully run the
> commands but that it does not know there is a daemon to monitor.

If you're using ufw, you can check if you're firewall is active with

```
sudo ufw status
```

ufw is a tool for managing netfilter firewall and that even if it is not running, if tables are set the firewall is working (i.e. if you configure your tables manually with iptables, the ufw doesn't need to be active).