# 'nfs-server' state in 'service_facts' is wrong and differ from 'ansible.builtin.systemd'

Tags: systemd, nfs, ansible

Running a CentOS 8 Stream server with `nfs-utils` version 2.3.3-57.el8 and using `ansible-playbook` core version 2.11.12 with a test playbook

```yaml
- hosts: server-1
  tasks:
    - name: Collect status
      service_facts:

      register: services_state
    - name: Print service_facts
      debug:
        var: services_state

    - name: Collect systemd status
      ansible.builtin.systemd:
        name: "nfs-server"
      register: sysd_service_state

    - name: Print systemd state
      debug:
        var: sysd_service_state
```

will render the following results

**service_facts**

```json
...
"nfs-server.service": {
                    "name": "nfs-server.service",
                    "source": "systemd",
                    "state": "stopped",
                    "status": "disabled"
},
...
```

**ansible.builtin.systemd**

```json
...
"name": "nfs-server",
        "status": {
            "ActiveEnterTimestamp": "Tue 2022-10-04 10:03:17 UTC",
            "ActiveEnterTimestampMonotonic": "7550614760",
            "ActiveExitTimestamp": "Tue 2022-10-04 09:05:43 UTC",
            "ActiveExitTimestampMonotonic": "4096596618",
            "ActiveState": "active",
...
```

The NFS Server is very much running/active but the `service_facts` fails to report it as such.

Other services, such as `httpd` reports correct state in `service_facts`.

Have I misunderstood or done something wrong here? Or have I run in to an anomaly?

Comment: Did you've got the chance to do further testing according [stackoverflow question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73958274/6771046)? If so, what are the test results?

Comment: I did take a look for the duplicate files you mentioned but they were not present in my system.

Comment: It also shows a process of how to test, which results are interesting and how to provide the test results. [ansible/modules/service_facts.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/service_facts.py#L220) seems to try and use different approaches of how to gather the actual status of services. This difference in reporting seems to come from that part.

Comment: After further investigation regarding Ansible Issue #[67262](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/67262) "_`service_facts` does not return correct state for services_", it might be that this is somehow caused by [What does status "`active (exited)`" mean for a systemd service?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/241970/) and [`def _list_rh(self, services)`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/service_facts.py#L147) and even if already set `RemainAfterExit=yes` within the `.service` files. Because the service seems not to be `running` but `exited`.

Comment: ... I've provided an update with more investigation under [`nfs-server` state in `service_facts` differ from `ansible.builtin.systemd`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73958274/6771046).